# Plotting locations on a NYC map using geopandas and geoplot

Tags: python, point, geopandas, shapely, geoplot

I have a file of store locations that I am trying to plot onto a NYC map. I have been using the below two links as my guide so far, but I have been unable to get the code to work.

- https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/quickstart/quickstart.html
- https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-101-plot-any-data-with-a-latitude-and-longitude-on-a-map-98e01944b972

```
import geopandas
import geoplot
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

store_locDF=pd.read_csv('stores.csv') #Import file
cols_to_keep=['store_longitude','store_latitude']
store_locDF = store_locDF[store_locDF.columns.intersection(cols_to_keep)] #Keep only long and lat

#Convert long and lat to "points"
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( store_locDF["store_longitude"],store_locDF["store_latitude"])]
#Store geometry in dataframe
store_locDF['geometry']=geometry

#print(store_locDF.head())

boroughs = geopandas.read_file(geoplot.datasets.get_path('nyc_boroughs'))

ax=geoplot.polyplot(boroughs,edgecolor='white', facecolor='lightgray',figsize=(12, 8))

geoplot.polyplot(geometry, ax=ax) #<--Didnt work
#geoplt.pointplot(geometry, ax=ax) <--Also didnt work
''''


The error I am getting is: 
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3c7d64229a6c> in <module>
     19 ax=geoplot.polyplot(boroughs,edgecolor='white', facecolor='lightgray',figsize=(12, 8))
     20 
---> 21 geoplot.polyplot(geometry, ax=ax)

~\anaconda3\envs\IST 652\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py in polyplot(df, projection, extent, figsize, ax, **kwargs)
    917             return ax
    918 
--> 919     plot = PolyPlot(df, figsize=figsize, ax=ax, extent=extent, projection=projection, **kwargs)
    920     return plot.draw()
    921 

~\anaconda3\envs\IST 652\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py in __init__(self, df, **kwargs)
    881     class PolyPlot(Plot):
    882         def __init__(self, df, **kwargs):
--> 883             super().__init__(df, **kwargs)
    884 
    885         def draw(self):

~\anaconda3\envs\IST 652\lib\site-packages\geoplot\geoplot.py in __init__(self, df, **kwargs)
    614             # self when it is asked for its geometry property, and so it will never be the source
    615             # of this error.
--> 616             raise ValueError(
    617                 'The input GeoDataFrame does not have a "geometry" column set.'
    618             )

ValueError: The input GeoDataFrame does not have a "geometry" column set.


Any help is appreciated
```

Comment: The full error includes information about where the error occurs. Please include it

Comment: Question has been updated. Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: You passed a list to `polyplot`. The error indicates that it expects a GeoDataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenter "Paul H" said, the problem was that I was feeding a list instead of a geodataframe. Below is the working code:

```
import geopandas
import geoplot
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

store_locDF=pd.read_csv('stores.csv')
cols_to_keep=['store_longitude','store_latitude']

crs={'init':'epsg:4326'}

boroughs = geopandas.read_file(geoplot.datasets.get_path('nyc_boroughs'))

geo_df=geopandas.GeoDataFrame(store_locDF,crs=crs,geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(store_locDF["store_longitude"], store_locDF["store_latitude"]))



fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
boroughs.plot(ax=ax,alpha=0.4,color="grey")
geo_df[geo_df['active_yn']=="Y"].plot(ax=ax,markersize=200, alpha=0.4,color="green", label="Active Store")
geo_df[geo_df['active_yn']=="N"].plot(ax=ax,markersize=200, alpha=0.4,color="red", label="Inactive Stores")
plt.legend()
```